# Algorithm to find the 'possible' combinations of variables with constraints in Matlab?

Tags: algorithm, matlab, combinations, probability

Say I have 7 items in A and 4 items in B

```
A=[10;40;90;130;200;260;320]
B=[100;300;500;1000]
```

I want to have the list of **possible combinations** where :

- All sub-components of **A** MUST be included
- sub-components of B can be added **until** the the *SUM* of all sub-componenets added is greater than 2000

Anyone has an idea how to do this in Matlab ?

My try :

```
X=sum(A);
y=1;
for Y=1:((length(A))-1);
   X=X+B(y);
   if(X>2000)
       disp('Following is unacceptable')    
   end
   y=y+1
end
```

However this code is not correct. It just adding the first element of B then adding it with the second element and so on. It isn't providing me with possible combinations.

Example :

- sum(A) + B(1) = OK
- sum(A) + B(4) = NOT OK
- sum(A) + B(1) + B(2) = OK
- sum(A) + B(2) + B(3) = OK
- etc...

I want this to be automated if values of A or B change in the future. I am not sure if this is a case of probability as well.

Comment: So what's the criteria for the best solution? The one with the highest sum? Is any solution with a sum over 2000 acceptable, or is it the solution with the least/most amount of elements from B? Please elucidate your question.

Comment: Already stated that any solution above 2000 is unacceptable. I just want all possible combinations that always result in a total of sum of less than 2000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use [`nchoosek`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nchoosek.html) and a double `for`-loop to go through all possible combinations of elements in `B`:

```
SA = sum(A);
for k = 1:numel(B)
    for idx = nchoosek(1:numel(B), k)'
        B_subset = B(idx);
        if (SA + sum(B_subset) <= 2000)
            disp([A(:)', B_subset(:)'])
        end
    end
end
```

This prints all combinations with a sum less than (or equal to) 2000. For your example we get:

```
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   100
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   300
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   500
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   100   300
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   100   500
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   300   500
    10    40    90   130   200   260   320   100   300   500
```

### Explanation:

**The inner `for`-loop**:
The inner `for`-loop uses `nchoosek(1:numel(B), k)`, which generates all k-length combinations out of 1...length(B) (I'm using [`numel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/numel.html) instead of [`length`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/length.html) out of habit; in this case it has the same effect). For example, in our case `B` has 4 elements, so for `k = 3` we get `nchoosek(1:4, 3)`:

```
    1   2   3
    1   2   4
    1   3   4
    2   3   4
```

What we get from this is all the possible k-length combinations of indices of elements in `B`. In each iteration, this `for`-loop assigns a different combination of indices to `idx`. How do we convert the indices of `B` to real elements? We simply write `B(idx)`.
Inside loop the combination is tested: if the total `sum(A) + sum(B(idx))` is less than (or equal to) 2000, that combination is displayed.

**The outer `for`-loop**:
The outer `for`-loop simply iterates over all possible lengths of combinations (that is, over all possible values of `k`).

Hope that helps!

### P.S:

Some MATLAB programming tips for the future:
1. Variable names are case-sensitive.
2. You don't need to increment the loop variable. The `for` loop does that automatically for you.

Comment: Wow this is the simplest out of all answers. Can you please comment on the code and describe how its working ? would love to learn.

Comment: @NLed sure, I've included a short explanation in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, for some reason I get the following error when I run it : `Error using horzcat CAT arguments dimensions are not consistent.`

Comment: Also, how can I display the String of the array B(1) B(2) instead of the actual integer value ?

Comment: @NLed I'm assuming that this is because `A` and `B` aren't either all rows or all columns. I've fixed my answer, see if it works now.

Comment: Thank you, thats the simplest out of all answers !

Comment: quick question : How do I remove any combination that has only one value of B..As in display values that are a combination of more than one values of B ?

Comment: @NLed Just make the outer loop start from `k=2` (instead of 1), since `k` indicates the number of elements in `B` to sum.

Comment: Also, what would be the best way to store these values ? Rather than display them only.

Comment: @NLed You can store them in a cell array, as they are of variable size.

Comment: what about normal arrays rather than cells ?? Because a cell displays `[2x1 double]` as an answer rather than the values

Comment: @NLed Normal arrays are not suitable here, for the reason stated in my previous post. Sometimes MATLAB displays the contents of cell arrays this way. You can use the `{:}` syntax to dump the contents. Alternatively, you can write a for-loop and print each cell individually.

Comment: can you look over http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177969/how-to-prioritise-one-combination-from-the-other-possibilities-in-matab/ -- Something similar to this

Answer (score 2):

Assuming B is not very long (around 10 elements), an exhaustive search through all combinations will work just fine. You can carry out this exhaustive search with a recursive function, but the code below uses a trick that's particularly concise in MATLAB: it sweeps through all combinations of the elements of B by representing each combination as a binary bit string.

```
% examine each of 2^length(B) combinations
for i=0:2^length(B)-1
    % converts the binary string into an array of 0 and 1 used to select elements in B
    combo = dec2bin(i, length(B))-'0'; 
    % print the combination of elements if their sum is large
    if combo * B + sum(A) > 2000
       disp(find(combo));
    end
end
```

There are 2^length(B) possible combinations. This examines them in turn, representing the combination as a binary string of length length(B), and evaluating the sum of these elements (with a dot product between the bit string and B).

Comment: Would appreciate it if you can add more explanation to what the code is exactly doing, I really want to learn rather than just copy/paste a code

Comment: So this shows the values of B that can be added along with A right ?? The printed values are the values that can be combined with sum(A) ?

Comment: the printed values are the indices of the entries of B that can be combined with those of A so that their sum exceeds 2000. if you want to print instead the elements of B (instead of their indices), write `B(find(combo))` instead of `find(combo)`.

Comment: and im assuiming if I reverse the inequality to <2000 I will get a list of values that give a combination with A that gives a sum less than 2000, correct ?

Answer (score 2):

The best approach would involve some recursion, like this:

```
sumA=sum(A);
find_CombinationsOfB(B,sumA,[])

function ret=findCombinationsOfB(in_vals,total_sum,already_contained)

if total_sum>2000
    ret=false;
else
    for y=1:length(in_vals);
       if (~findCombinationsOfB(in_vals([1:(y-1);(y+1):length(in_vals)],total_sum+in_vals(y),[already_contained in_vals(y))
          display([already_contained in_vals])
       end
    end
    ret=true;
end
```

Essentially what this does is tries each combination of B. It will print any that don't add up to 2000, including the sum from A.

Step by step, here's what it does:

1. Initially, the full array of B is passed, along with the sum of A. An empty array is passed to store which elements of B have been used so far.
2. Each element added in turn to the function, and called again with a new sum, and with a value missing from the array.
3. If at any point the array sum is over 2000, it stops that chain of reasoning.

If you want to know more about how this works, print in_vals, total_sum, and already_contained in the start of the function, like this:

```
fprintf("in_vals=%s   total_sum=%i   already_contained=%s",mat2str(in_vals),total_sum,mat2str(already_contained));
```

It should show you at each iteration what is happening.

Comment: Can you please elaborate what the code does ? I want to learn how this works rather than copy it.

Comment: I get the following error : `??? Undefined function or method 'find_CombinationsOfB' for input arguments of
type 'double'.`

Comment: Probably how it's set up. You have to either put the function in it's own file, or make the base file a function.